# Converting given mantissa, exponent, and sign to float?

Tags: c, floating-point, data-conversion, mantissa

I am given the mantissa, exponent, and sign and I have to convert it into the corresponding float. I am using 22 bits for mantissa, 9 bits for exponent, and 1 bit for the sign.

I conceptually know how to convert them into a float, first adjusting the exponent back to its place, then converting the resulting number back into a float, but I'm having trouble implementing this in C. I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512768/convert-sign-bit-exponent-and-mantissa-to-float), but I couldn't understand the code, and I'm not sure the answer is even right. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I need to code it in C

Edit:  I've made some progress by first converting the mantissa into binary, then adjusting the decimal point of the binary, then converting the decimal-point binary back into the actual float. I based my conversion functions off these two GeekforGeek pages ([one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-c/), [two](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-binary-fraction-decimal/)) But it seems like doing all these binary conversions is doing it the long and hard way. The link above apparently does it in very little steps by using the >> operators, but I don't understand exactly how that results in a float.

Comment: Do you need to code it in C or C++? Also what exactly don't you understand from the link you provided, and what have you tried to implement so far?

Comment: @Cerenia, Sorry I didn't mention I need to code in C. What I didn't understand in the link was what the Converted[ ] variable was and what it did exactly. Convert has four elements and I don't understand the author uses it to produce the final float.

Comment: you just need an enough long int for 32b and to use arithmetic << and | to fill your IEEE 32b float

Comment: I think all the op does is write down the input he has into this datatype for ease of use. Unfortunately I am not comfortable enough in pure C to help. But maybe this resource will give you an idea: https://indepth.dev/the-simple-math-behind-decimal-binary-conversion-algorithms/
Relevant for you would be the *Converting fraction integer to decimal* and to get to fractions in the first place also *Base-q expansion of a number*.

Comment: In the link *Converted* is an array of byte containing the 4 bytes making the float, as you can see each part is shift by 24 and 16 and 8 and (not done of course) 0. In your case this is different because you do not have the 4 bytes but the mantissa, exponent and sign separately. But the process is similar. What blocks you ? what you tried ?

Comment: @bruno, what blocked me was that I didn't understand what exactly Converted did. I sort of understand what you explained though. How could I adapt what the link has to what I need to do? I've made some progress by first converting the mantissa into binary, then adjusting the decimal point of the binary, then converting the decimal-point binary back into the actual float. But it seems like doing all these binary conversions is doing it the long and hard way. Could you explain the process I need to do from the link?

Comment: "long and hard way" : how is possible ? Edit your question showing what you did. "Could you explain the process I need to do from the link"  : in both case you have bit fields and have to group them placing each at the right place in the float

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `22:9:1` for mantissa, biased exponent and sign-bit. IEEE-754 Single-Precision Floating-Point uses `23:8:1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a program with comments explaining the decoding:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//  Define constants describing the floating-point encoding.
enum
{
    SignificandBits = 22,   //  Number of bits in signficand field.
    ExponentBits    =  9,   //  Number of bits in exponent field.

    ExponentMaximum = (1 << ExponentBits) - 1,
    ExponentBias    = (1 << ExponentBits-1) - 1,
};


/*  Given the contents of the sign, exponent, and significand fields that
    encode a floating-point number following IEEE-754 patterns for binary
    floating-point, return the encoded number.

    "double" is used for the return type as not all values represented by the
    sample format (9 exponent bits, 22 significand bits) will fit in a "float"
    when it is the commonly used IEEE-754 binary32 format.
*/
double DecodeCustomFloat(
    unsigned SignField, uint32_t ExponentField, uint32_t SignificandField)
{
    /*  We are given a significand field as an integer, but it is used as the
        value of a binary numeral consisting of “.” followed by the significand
        bits.  That value equals the integer divided by 2 to the power of the
        number of significand bits.  Define a constant with that value to be
        used for converting the significand field to represented value.
    */
    static const double SignificandRatio = (uint32_t) 1 << SignificandBits;

    /*  Decode the sign field:

            If the sign bit is 0, the sign is +, for which we use +1.
            If the sign bit is 1, the sign is -, for which we use -1.
    */
    double Sign = SignField ? -1. : +1.;

    //  Dispatch to handle the different categories of exponent field.
    switch (ExponentField)
    {
        /*  When the exponent field is all ones, the value represented is a
            NaN or infinity:

                If the significand field is zero, it is an infinity.
                Otherwise, it is a NaN.  In either case, the sign should be
                preserved.

            Note this is a simple demonstration implementation that does not
            preserve the bits in the significand field of a NaN -- we just
            return the generic NAN without attempting to set its significand
            bits.
        */
        case ExponentMaximum:
        {
            return Sign * (SignificandField ? NAN : INFINITY);
        }

        /*  When the exponent field is not all zeros or all ones, the value
            represented is a normal number:

                The exponent represented is ExponentField - ExponentBias, and
                the significand represented is the value given by the binary
                numeral “1.” followed by the significand bits.
        */
        default:
        {
            int    Exponent = ExponentField - ExponentBias;
            double Significand = 1 + SignificandField / SignificandRatio;
            return Sign * ldexp(Significand, Exponent);
        }

        /*  When the exponent field is zero, the value represented is subnormal:

                The exponent represented is 1 - ExponentBias, and the
                significand represented is the value given by the binary
                numeral “0.” followed by the significand bits.
        */
        case 0:
        {
            int    Exponent = 1 - ExponentBias;
            double Significand = 0 + SignificandField / SignificandRatio;
            return Sign * ldexp(Significand, Exponent);
        }
    }
}


/*  Test that a given set of fields decodes to the expected value and
    print the fields and the decoded value.
*/
static void Demonstrate(
    unsigned SignField, uint32_t SignificandField, uint32_t ExponentField,
    double Expected)
{
    double Observed
        = DecodeCustomFloat(SignField, SignificandField, ExponentField);

    if (! (Observed == Expected) && ! (isnan(Observed) && isnan(Expected)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Error, expected (%u, %" PRIu32 ", %" PRIu32 ") to represent "
            "%g (hexadecimal %a) but got %g (hexadecimal %a).\n",
            SignField, SignificandField, ExponentField,
            Expected, Expected,
            Observed, Observed);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf(
        "(%u, %" PRIu32 ", %" PRIu32 ") represents %g (hexadecimal %a).\n",
        SignField, SignificandField, ExponentField, Observed, Observed);
}


int main(void)
{
    Demonstrate(0, 0, 0, +0.);
    Demonstrate(1, 0, 0, -0.);
    Demonstrate(0, 255, 0, +1.);
    Demonstrate(1, 255, 0, -1.);
    Demonstrate(0, 511, 0, +INFINITY);
    Demonstrate(1, 511, 0, -INFINITY);
    Demonstrate(0, 511, 1, +NAN);
    Demonstrate(1, 511, 1, -NAN);
    Demonstrate(0, 0, 1, +0x1p-276);
    Demonstrate(1, 0, 1, -0x1p-276);
    Demonstrate(0, 255, 1, +1. + 0x1p-22);
    Demonstrate(1, 255, 1, -1. - 0x1p-22);
    Demonstrate(0, 1, 0, +0x1p-254);
    Demonstrate(1, 1, 0, -0x1p-254);
    Demonstrate(0, 510, 0x3fffff, +0x1p256 - 0x1p233);
    Demonstrate(1, 510, 0x3fffff, -0x1p256 + 0x1p233);
}
```

Some notes:

- `ldexp` is a standard C library function. `ldexp(x, e)` returns `x` multiplied by 2 to the power of `e`.
- `uint32_t` is an unsigned 32-bit integer type. It is defined in `stdint.h`.
- `"%" PRIu32` provides a `printf` conversion specification for formatting a `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program to illustrate how to break a `float` into its components and how to compose a `float` value from a (sign, exponent, mantissa) triplet:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void dumpbits(uint32_t bits, int n) {
    while (n--)
        printf("%d%c", (bits >> n) & 1, ".|"[!n]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned sign = 0;
    unsigned exponent = 127;
    unsigned long mantissa = 0;
    union {
        float f32;
        uint32_t u32;
    } u;

    if (argc == 2) {
        u.f32 = strtof(argv[1], NULL);
        sign = u.u32 >> 31;
        exponent = (u.u32 >> 23) & 0xff;
        mantissa = (u.u32) & 0x7fffff;
        printf("%.8g -> sign:%u, exponent:%u, mantissa:0x%06lx\n",
               (double)u.f32, sign, exponent, mantissa);
        printf("+s+----exponent---+------------------mantissa-------------------+\n");
        printf("|");
        dumpbits(sign, 1);
        dumpbits(exponent, 8);
        dumpbits(mantissa, 23);
        printf("\n");
        printf("+-+---------------+---------------------------------------------+\n");
    } else {
        if (argc > 1) sign = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
        if (argc > 2) exponent = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);
        if (argc > 3) mantissa = strtol(argv[3], NULL, 0);
        u.u32 = (sign << 31) | (exponent << 23) | mantissa;
        printf("sign:%u, exponent:%u, mantissa:0x%06lx -> %.8g\n",
               sign, exponent, mantissa, (double)u.f32);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that contrary to your assignment, the size of the mantissa is 23 bits and the exponent has 8 bits, which correspond to the IEEE 754 Standard for 32-bit aka *single-precision* float. See the Wikipedia article on [Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: It is not uncommon for class assignments to use non-standard formats so that students have to write their own code for encoding and decoding, since the native format will not work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: If indeed it is a requirement, I leave it up to the OP to adjust the code :)

Answer (score -1):

Linked question is C++ not C. To convert between datatypes in C preserving bits, a tool to use is the union. Something like

```
union float_or_int {
  uint32_t i;
  float f;
}

float to_float(uint32_t mantissa, uint32_t exponent, uint32_t sign)
{
  union float_or_int result;
  result.i = (sign << 31) | (exponent << 22) | mantissa;
  return result.f;
}
```

Sorry for typos, it's been a while since I've coded in C

Comment: Sorry, it keeps returning 0.000 floats, what could be the problem?

Comment: The question describes a custom floating-point format. This answer simply puts the bits of the custom floating-point format into the bits of a native `float`. Unless the native `float` uses the same format as the custom format, this cannot work. And no common C implementations use the custom format described in the question.

Comment: Additionally, if `int` is 32 bits or less, then `sign << 31` overflows when `sign` is 1, and the resulting behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Eric is right about the overflow. Function can take unsigned int to fix this.